# how to replace a specific query param in inertia vue?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I m trying to create a searchable list in a edit screen of my project. its laravel inertia vue project. i'm using this.$inertia.get() function and i want to filter some data according to my query param. filtering is working as i expected. but i want to hide that query param from the url.

for an example:

`http://my-site.test/shows/2`.

and i have tried these codes for get results.

```js
this.$inertia.get(route('shows.edit', {id: 2, _query: {term: event.target.value}}, {replace:  true}), {}, {preserveState: true});
```

and

```js
this.$inertia.get('/shows/2/', {term: event.target.value}, {preserveState: true, replace: true});
```

But none of these are worked as i expected. When i search something in the search field my address bar changes like this:

`http://my-site.test/shows/2?term=dfgddfg`

But i don't want to stay the **term** param in browser history. Is there a way to replace only the **term** param.

I followed below youtube video to get a reference.

[Create a searchable select field with Laravel, InertiaJS and vue-multiselect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPCO8kzDvp4)

Comment: If you don't want the "term" param to be appended as a query string, you'll need to change this.$inertia.get for this.$inertia.post and then redirect()->back() on your controller.